# Form input required message doesn't disappear after input is made

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Refer [this codepen link](http://codepen.io/shirodkarsohan/pen/kkGEgR?editors=1000)

I have a simple form built using angular material.  have referred [angular material demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) for this.

The fields are marked required and if the input is not made then a `field required` message is displayed. But the message doesn't vanish once a valid entry is made. Whereas, in the official demo this works.

This is the HTML code pertaining to the form:

```
<form name="myform">
<md-input-container flex="50">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input required name="name" ng-model="project.name">
  <div ng-messages="myform.name.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
  </div>
 </md-input-container>
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input required type="email" name="email" ng-model="project.email"
           minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />

    <div ng-messages="myform.email.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
        Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Submit</md-button>
</form>
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inject `ngMessages` to your app.

```
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
```